# Flimsy or fragile?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

When writing a review about a product, is there any difference between saying a certain part of it is flimsy or fragile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you looked at the dictionary definitions, you may find that they are similar, but the connotations that they carry differ.

To me, this is a fragile object:

[image]

It looks like it needs to be handled with care, or it will shatter. Not just break, but actually shatter (break into lots of pieces).

On the other hand, this looks flimsy to me:

[image]

It looks like it'll break from use, and doesn't have much weight to it.

You'll also notice that the vase that I described as "fragile" is *supposed* to be fragile. It is made that way. It isn't a bad thing - it is an inherent property of fine things. The plastic phone case, on the other hand, is not supposed to be flimsy - we want something sturdy. Flimsy often carries a negative connotation. The object isn't supposed to be that way.

Answer (score 4):

To me, the difference is that flimsy implies that it is likely to break if correctly used while fragile implies it is likely to break if incorrectly used.  For example:

A pair of headphones would be flimsy if the cord is easily damaged when plugged/unplugged, while it would be fragile if dropping it would break it.

Answer (score 0):

Fragile is when something can be broken very easily like glass and flimsy is when something is very thin and can be damaged easily.